# How can I create my solana wallet

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, solana-pay

I'm new here in Solana. I want to create a wallet so I can send my earnings from hive-mapper and use it for staking, I thought I successfully created a wallet account but it seems I created a community account instead. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

It's good to get started with hot wallets like [Phantom](https://phantom.app/download) to easily interact with dapps.

For more security, I would personally recommend [Exodus](https://www.exodus.com/download/).

If you're already familiar with [Solana CLI](https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/file-system-wallet#generate-a-file-system-wallet-keypair), you can easily create one and import it for any wallet apps.

As long as your funds grow, you can consider using cold wallets (Ledger) for better secure your assets!